# Memory Leak with NSUserDefaults and NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am defining a few NSMutableArrays from data stored in NSUserDefaults like this:

```
    nameArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"names"]]mutableCopy];
```

and I am releasing in dealloc.

nameArray is defined in my view controller's header file inside of @interface because it its scope is supposed to be the entire class.

There seems to be a memory leak related to it (the Instruments leak utility tells me so).

Does anybody see anything wrong with what I am doing that might cause a leak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `mutableCopy` invocation, you don't need it since you're already `alloc/init`-ing an `NSMutableArray`:

```
nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"names"]];
```

`mutableCopy` is the culprit here because it increments the retain count of the receiver (which is already 1), so when you invoke `release` in your `-dealloc` method, the retain count decrements to 1, not 0.

You don't need to invoke `mutableCopy` because you're passing the array into an `NSMutableArray` initializer, which will inherently make your new array mutable.

Comment: I could have sworn I had set it up the same way minus mutable copy before and it kept giving me errors saying I was trying to mutate a non-mutable structure. Maybe I changed something in the meantime though. I'll give that a try and let you know if that works.

Comment: If it said that, it could mean that you defined nameArray as NSArray, not NSMutableArray.

Comment: Wow, no more leaks! Thanks so much! 
I guess I was confused about when to use mutableCopy. When I had the non-mutable problem, that made me think that I needed to use mutableCopy every time I needed a mutable array I guess.

Comment: Jaanus - thanks but I'm pretty sure I had defined it as a mutable array but possibly didn't alloc/init and it was not mutable until I added mutablecopy in that case. Can anybody explain further?

Comment: `mutableCopy` doesn't retain the receiver, it creates a new object—a copy of the old. Unlike `copy`, this cannot be effectively done without actually making a copy; a `mutableCopy` must always actually make a mutable copy.